# AngularJS: init data from js timer not working

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular. i was reading the functionality of `$scope.$apply();`
i got a sample where controller's data member value is assign from timer but change was not reflected in UI but when i use  `$scope.$apply();` then change reflect to UI.........why?

i define timer inside my controller so if i assign any data to controller's data member then change should come. tell me what was the problem with timer that if we assign any data to controller's data member change is not coming to UI.

### see my code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
{{message}}
<br>

 <button ng-click="myFunc()">OK</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope ){
$scope.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        // AngularJS unaware of update to $scope
        alert("alert called");
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 2000);

$scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is javascript function. it causes digest cycle to stop running. That's why you need to use `$scope.$apply()` to manually start the digest cycle.

alternatively, you can use `$timeout` service instead of `setTimeout`. `$timeout` is angular in build service so it will not cause any problems to the digest cycle

```
$timeout(function () {
        $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        // AngularJS unaware of update to $scope
        alert("alert called");
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 2000);
```

Make sure to inject the `$timeout` to your controller

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS provides a handy wrapper for this: `$timeout()` - it does the `$apply()` call for us so we don't have to. Magic!

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  {{vm.message}}
  <br>

  <button ng-click="vm.myFunc()">OK</button>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)


function MainController($timeout) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.myFunc = myFunc;
  vm.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";

  function myFunc() {
    vm.message = "Timeout called!";
  }

  $timeout(myFunc, 2000);

}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/44fe8ve0/)

Answer (score 1):

use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service of angular, not native javascript `settimeout`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
    // AngularJS unaware of update to $scope
    alert("alert called");
    //$scope.$apply();
  }, 2000);

  $scope.myFunc = function() {
    $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  {{message}}
  <br>

  <button ng-click="myFunc()">OK</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **$timeout** service in your application, which has automatic **$apply()** inside that. This should resolve your issue.